# Azure Functions with VS Code and Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am developing my first Function App with Python and VS Code, converting a local python script that worked to be scheduled. I have run across the following error that I am unable to solve:

`Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.`

My original python script had local files that I referenced by filepath, but naturally for Azure Functions, I need to access blob storage so I made the appropriate changes to file download / upload and import references. I am only testing it locally at the moment with func start, and my function is http triggered.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1.) Changed my import references to:

`from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient`

2.) Verified I'm working in my virtual environment in the terminal, .venv
3.) Add 'azure-storage-blob' to my requirements.txt file
3.) `pip install --target .python_packages/lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt`
4.) `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5.) Added additional values in my local.settings.json file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "PYTHONPATH": ".python_packages/lib/site-packages",
    "python": ".venv/Scripts/python.exe"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabaseConnectionString": "my_connection_string"
  }
}
```

6.) Deleted and recreated the virtual environment and running steps 3 and 4 again.
7.) Verified that the selected python interpreter is 3.10.10 which matches what is in my virtual environment

The only other information I've come across is that azure.storage package was deprecated which is why I install azure-storage-blob. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Hello @robkru12 Please check if [AzureFunctionCoretools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash) is installed .In visual studio code  was able to do what operation you asked and make sure install required Azure Extention in [visual studio code](https://i.imgur.com/AbmCaOD.png) and  install `pip install azure-storage-blob`

Comment: Hello @Sampath. I have Azure Core Function Tools installed as I am able to use the func start command to run the function locally. Additionally, I do have the Azure extension installed and am able to see my local function project in the workspace dropdown. When I use that command, it informs me that all of the requirements were already satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the error. My Python environment seemed to be flawed so I recreated the project. Firstly, I was using Python 3.10 when only up to version 3.9 is supported at the moment. I selected the Python 3.9.0 interpreter and adjusted the following settings in the project folder:

1.) ProjectFolder/.vscode/settings.json - add the following line to the json:

"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "ProjectFolderPath/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"

2.) ProjectFolder/local.settings.json - add the following line to Values:

"PYTHONPATH": "./ProjectFolderName"

Afterwards, I deleted my virtual environment, recreated it, ran the pip install -r requirements.txt command in the terminal with the virtual environment activated, and now my function works.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `azure-storage-blob` indicates that the module `azure-storage-blob` is not installed. Using Http Trigger, I Uploaded and downloaded the file in Python 3.10.10.

**Reference:**

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_containers.py) for Uploading and downloading the file.

- **For Uploading the file** :

```py
req_body = req.get_json()
connect_str = req_body.get('connect_str')
container_name = req_body.get('container_name')
file_path = req_body.get('file_path')
file_str = req_body.get('file_str')
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_path)
blob_client.upload_blob(file_str, overwrite=True)
return  func.HttpResponse(f"File uploaded to blob storage account: {file_path}")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- **For downloading the file** :

```py
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(account_conn_str)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

with  open(os.path.join(local_path, blob_name), "wb") as  download_file:
download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
download_file.write(download_stream.readall())
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Blob {blob_name} downloaded to {local_path} successfully.")
```

[image]

- Check the respective local path [given].(https://i.imgur.com/WynPU7y.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was able to structure the python code to correctly upload and download blob data, just confused on the mismatch between the Azure function claiming that azure.storage is not installed and what is confirmed to be installed.

Comment: To confirm, the function is not working. I receive that module not found error before I am able to test the upload and dowload of blob data; however, I did have it structured similar to yours.

Comment: Did you use the pip command which i sent

Comment: Yes. When I enter that command into the terminal, the output in the terminal states that the requirements have already been satisfied. When I run the 'func start' command in the terminal again, I get the same error that I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: And to confirm, I am in the virtual environment when I run these commands.

Comment: Hello @robkru I will look into all possible cases of [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Hello, Sampath. Were you able to discover any other possible solutions?

Comment: Hello, @robbru another possible solution is: In the integrated terminal where the [virtual environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash) is activated, use pip to install the packages you defined `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, `pip install azure-storage-blob` [and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process) [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-python-get-started.md)

Comment: In the integrated terminal, activate the virtual environment in the current folder, depending on your operating system:


Windows


`.venv\scripts\activate`

Comment: Open the [requirements.txt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows%2Cvs-code-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-decorators) in the editor and change its content to the following code:


`azure-functions`